# Singular vs. plural in the term "works" for an industrial facility

Tags: vocabulary, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

The term *works* is used for industrial facilities, like *ironworks* and *steelworks*. Despite the -s suffix, I've seen it used as a singular form. I don't think there is distinct word for the plural form.

What is the proper use of *works* in singular or plural?

Comment: You are right.  The plural form generally means a factory or the place where something is made. As a singular form it can mean either the skill or the practice or a piece of work: ironwork, handiwork, metalwork, needlework, woodwork and so on.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, how would I refer to several steel facilities? That is, what is the plural of works? And does it feel right to talk about "an ironworks"?

Comment: It's the same. "There are two steelworks in the town." And yes, it feels perfectly correct to speak of "an ironworks."